# Dimensions of rectangular parallelopiped of maximum volume...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

i Need to calculate volume of parallelopiped of maximum volume with edges parallel to the coordinate axes that can be incribed in a ellipseoid $(x/a)^{2} + (y/b)^{2} + (z/c)^{2} =1$ .

Apparently there is no problem in solving question .BUT I TOOK volume V=xyz with x,y,z are dimensions of  rectangular parallelopiped .

Doubt : In textbook they have taken V=8xyz with dimensions $2x,2y,2z$ while i have taken $x,y,z$ . So i am getting coordinated with each coordinate divided by 1\2 than that of answer . I want to know why they have taken dimensions like this and maximize $8xyz$ instead of $xyz$ ..

Comment: Coordinates of a vertex and length of the edges of the solid are not the same thing of course. They wanted to avoid the division by 2.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo i didnt get you .but shoudnt answer be same ?

Comment: The authors made another choice: the variables in the textbook are the coordinates of the vertex of the solid in the first octant. By simmetry the lengths of the edges are $\dots$

Comment: @TonyPiccolo is this parallelopiped  below xy plane as to what it is above it  .is this reason for 2x ,2y...

Comment: See in this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617178/volume-of-a-largest-rectangular-parallelepiped-inscribed-in-an-ellipsoid) the accepted answer.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Thanks

Comment: If you took $x$, $y$, and $z$ to be the dimensions of the box, then you can't say that they satisfy the equation of the ellipsoid, can you?